# Needing to reload page to see entire contents

Tags: product-attribute

Thanks in advance for your help! I am using the Magento Open Source ver 2.4.5 with the breeze-evolution theme from Swissup labs. Currently when I navigate from one page to another, the page does not fully load. For example, when i click on a Product, it navigates to the Product Page, but the breadcrumbs at the top to navigate to the Home page, Product Attributes does not load (as shown in image1 below). When I reload the page, these become visible (image 2). This is the same behaviour when I go back to Home page by clicking on the logo - the product attributes on hover disappear (image 3) and on reloading they are available again (image 4). Please advise

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below is the log from console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'referrer')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (turbo.js:131:31)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
    at e.dispatch (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:1411)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterVisitingLocation (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:2327)
    at r.startVisit (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:3026)
    at r.historyPoppedToLocationWithRestorationIdentifier (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:32402)
    at r.onPopState (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:11540)
    at turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:10667
(anonymous) @ turbo.js:131
Ra @ cash-8.1.2.min.js:28
e.dispatch @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.notifyApplicationAfterVisitingLocation @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.startVisit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.historyPoppedToLocationWithRestorationIdentifier @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.onPopState @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
turbo.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')
    at HTMLDocument.onBeforeCache (turbo.js:69:20)
    at e.dispatch (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:1411)
    at r.notifyApplicationBeforeCachingSnapshot (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:2455)
    at r.cacheSnapshot (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:88)
    at r.cacheSnapshot (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29619)
    at r.<anonymous> (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:26655)
    at turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29803
onBeforeCache @ turbo.js:69
e.dispatch @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.notifyApplicationBeforeCachingSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.cacheSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.cacheSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
requestAnimationFrame (async)
r.render @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.loadCachedSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visitStarted @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.start @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.startVisit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.historyPoppedToLocationWithRestorationIdentifier @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.onPopState @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
main.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadedScripts')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:228:45)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
    at e.dispatch (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:1411)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:2784)
    at r.visitCompleted (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:3409)
    at r.complete (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:25550)
    at r.<anonymous> (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:26825)
    at turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29803
(anonymous) @ main.js:228
Ra @ cash-8.1.2.min.js:28
e.dispatch @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.visitCompleted @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.complete @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
requestAnimationFrame (async)
r.render @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.loadCachedSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visitStarted @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.start @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.startVisit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.historyPoppedToLocationWithRestorationIdentifier @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.onPopState @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
dropdown.js:126 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:126:15)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
(anonymous) @ dropdown.js:126
Ra @ cash-8.1.2.min.js:28
dropdown-dialog.js:213 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).children(...).dropdownDialog is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dropdown-dialog.js:213:78)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
(anonymous) @ dropdown-dialog.js:213
Ra @ cash-8.1.2.min.js:28
collapsible.js:210 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).closest(...).collapsible is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (collapsible.js:210:96)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
(anonymous) @ collapsible.js:210
Ra @ cash-8.1.2.min.js:28
turbo.js:131 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'referrer')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (turbo.js:131:31)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
    at e.dispatch (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:1411)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterVisitingLocation (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:2327)
    at r.startVisit (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:3026)
    at r.startVisitToLocationWithAction (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:31379)
    at r.visitProposedToLocationWithAction (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:9376)
    at r.visit (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:31181)
    at r.clickBubbled (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:1615)
    at turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29991
(anonymous) @ turbo.js:131
Ra @ cash-8.1.2.min.js:28
e.dispatch @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.notifyApplicationAfterVisitingLocation @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.startVisit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.startVisitToLocationWithAction @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visitProposedToLocationWithAction @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.clickBubbled @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
turbo.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')
    at HTMLDocument.onBeforeCache (turbo.js:69:20)
    at e.dispatch (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:1411)
    at r.notifyApplicationBeforeCachingSnapshot (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:2455)
    at r.cacheSnapshot (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:88)
    at r.cacheSnapshot (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29619)
    at r.<anonymous> (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:26953)
    at turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29803
onBeforeCache @ turbo.js:69
e.dispatch @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.notifyApplicationBeforeCachingSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.cacheSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.cacheSnapshot @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
requestAnimationFrame (async)
r.render @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.loadResponse @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visitRequestCompleted @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.requestCompletedWithResponse @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
(anonymous) @ turbo.js:142
r.endRequest @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
Turbolinks.HttpRequest.requestLoaded @ turbo.js:138
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
load (async)
r.createXHR @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.issueRequest @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visitStarted @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.start @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.startVisit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
r.startVisitToLocationWithAction @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visitProposedToLocationWithAction @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.visit @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
r.clickBubbled @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5
main.js:228 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadedScripts')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:228:45)
    at HTMLDocument.Ra (cash-8.1.2.min.js:28:374)
    at e.dispatch (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:1411)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:2784)
    at r.visitCompleted (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:6:3409)
    at r.complete (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:25550)
    at r.<anonymous> (turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:27286)
    at turbolinks-5.2.0.min.js:5:29803
```

Comment: Are you facing any errors in the browser console? then please post it.

Comment: Your provided steps you follow again but before you need to remove first error log then when following steps you should check console error. I think you will get error in console.

Comment: If JS/CSS bundling or minifying is enable please disable it than check please.

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt response, I really appreciate your time! Below is the console log

Comment: @Ankit i tried the solution you provided, but sorry that did not work

php bin/magento config:set  dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0
php bin/magento cache:clean